# How to achieve search in code for dynamic-created text using PHP code as shortcode in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I need to move certain articles on my website, all of them, to another unique category. I am using specific phrases which are at bottom of every article, but after code execution, only two articles are moved to a new category, not all of them.

Also when I search through all posts using the native Dashboard-All posts option, it returns only those two articles, not all of them. I assume that is because the text is not stored in the database because it shows only when the post renders itself on the front end.

How can I include dynamically created text in my code?

My code, just for reference:

```
<?php
// Move to the category Breaking News.
$target_category_id = 1982;

// Get all posts that contain the search phrase from Syndication.
$posts = get_posts(
    array(
        's'              => 'and has been published here with permission',
        'post_status'    => 'any',
        'posts_per_page' => -1, // This will retrieve all posts.
    )
);

// Loop through the posts and move them to the target category.
foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
    // Remove the post from any existing categories.
    $current_categories = wp_get_post_categories( $post->ID );
    wp_remove_object_terms( $post->ID, $current_categories, 'category' );

    // Add the post to the target category.
    wp_set_post_categories( $post->ID, array( $target_category_id ), true );
}
```

That specific phrase is created dynamically because I am using the **WP Broadcast plugin** to add text at the bottom of every broadcasted article, but I am not sure if that phrase is stored in a database or that text is dynamically populated (created) every time post is rendered on the frontend.

This is the code I am using to generate a message (*and has been published here with permission*) at the bottom of every article:

```
<?php
function broadcasted_from() {
    // Check that Broadcast is enabled.
    if ( ! function_exists( 'ThreeWP_Broadcast' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Load the broadcast data for this post.
    global $post;
    $broadcast_data = ThreeWP_Broadcast()->get_post_broadcast_data( get_current_blog_id(), $post->ID );
    // This post must be a child. Check for a parent.
    $parent = $broadcast_data->get_linked_parent();
    if ( ! $parent ) {
        return;
    }

    // Fetch the permalink
    switch_to_blog( $parent['blog_id'] );
    $blog_name = get_bloginfo( 'name' );
    $permalink = get_post_permalink( $parent['post_id'] );
    restore_current_blog();

    // And now assemble a text.
    $r = sprintf( 'This article appeared in <a href="%s">%s</a> and has been published here with permission.', $permalink, $blog_name );
    return $r;
}
add_shortcode( 'broadcasted_from', 'broadcasted_from' );

add_filter(
    'the_content',
    function( $content ) {
        // Get the broadcast from the text.
        $sc_text = do_shortcode( '[broadcasted_from]' );
        // Add the text to the content.
        $content .= $sc_text;
        // Return the expanded content.
        return $content;
    }
);
```

Comment: If you are generating that text dynamically at the bottom of _every_ article, then why do you need to select _specific_ articles now, and not just - all of them?

Comment: Every broadcasted article, not all articles in database, as you can see from my post, where I mentioned Broadcaster WP plugin - only those articles should be moved to specific category.

Comment: So broadcasted articles would be those that contain the shortcode `[broadcasted_from]` then? Try and use that as the "search term" then perhaps. (If the shortcode takes additional arguments, then it would make sense to look for just `[broadcasted_from`.)

Comment: Nope, it returns null value, same if I use broadcasted_from as a meta-tag in search. This makes me crazy, man :(

Comment: Ah, I see now, the shortcode does not appear to actually be contained in the post content stored in the database - it gets added afterwards, using the `the_content` filter. _"as you can see from my post, where I mentioned Broadcaster WP plugin - only those articles"_ - I don't know that plugin, so I don't know what actually _makes_ "only those posts" be _those_ in the first place.

Comment: I asked developer of the plugin too, he does not have any answer for me :( WOW!

Comment: The shortcode gets added to _all_ posts indiscriminately here. Whether it outputs something or not, depends on whether `$broadcast_data->get_linked_parent()` returns a parent or not. So you'd have to go look into what that actually does.